# 55+ communities bulding in Florida

Tags: united-states, real-estate

I'm a non US citizen; my father and I are looking to invest in an apartment in Florida.
I have found 55+ communities that are on our price range. But I’m not 55.
Can people under 55 live in a 55+ communities for a short time (2 months)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a general description of what I have seen rather than a one size fits all answer and it is not necessarily up to date since state laws and local regulations may vary and may change.

The typical new Florida 55+ community requires that one owner be at least 55 years old.  Adult children who are 21 to 55 can reside there as well.  20% of initial buyers can be age 21 to 55 though some communities eliminate this provision once the last new unit is sold and the community then elects its first Board of Directors and begins running the development.  Children under the age of 21 can visit for extended periods, say a month, but permanent residence is not allowed.

Many of these communities enact rules to regulate investment properties.  As an example, a new owner might not be allowed to rent until one year after purchase.  The  rental contract length might have to be at least 6 months and only one tenant per year.  These restrictions vary.

It might be a problem if a 55 year old parent bought one of these homes but his/her child between the age of 21 and 55 lived there alone.  BoDs would likely challenge this.

The short answer is to obtain a copy of the community's Rules and Regulations to see what restrictions apply

Comment: My experience is that owners do not have to be over 55.  Residents do, and there is typically a holding period that precludes renting of a year or more.  But if an adult child wants to purchase for their parent or grandparent to reside, that is a welcomed situation.

Answer (score 5):

These communities have rules about the minimum ages for residents, and how long people younger than that can stay. The rules generally allow younger family members to make "short visits". This covers grand kids and their parents visiting for a week or two in the summer or over the holidays.

The property manager should be able to provide you with the rules and answer any questions.